# Safari in watir-webdriver (send_keys) function not working

Tags: testing, safari, watir

```
b.send_keys :tab
```

That line above doesn't work with safari on my mac. I am running watir-webdriver 0.6.1 and selenium-webdriver 2.22.2.

I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: b.send_keys :tab
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

I haven't installed safari-driver. Just running directly with the help of the above 2 gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari support has only recently been added to webdriver, and as far as I know you can't drive safari without safari-driver (which takes the form of an safari browser extension that you need to compile.

To quote from the Selenium site:

> While ready for use, the SafariDriver still requires a bit of manual
>   intervention before you can start writing tests. If you're not
>   comfortable checking out and building the Selenium project from
>   source, you may want to wait for us to make a general SafariDriver
>   release.

i'd start by following the instructions [here](http://watirwebdriver.com/safari/)

If you are not comfortable with that, I'd test against Firefox or Chrome (which represent a much larger userbase in any event)

Comment: Thanks for the answer chuck. But I'm 100% confident I'm driving safari without safari-driver extension. I guess I can try installing the extension manually and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Considering everything I've read says you need that extension to drive safari, I don't see how you could be making it work without it.

Comment: I'm resorting to finding a workaround for the full screen mode.. but I hope the webdriver team integrates this function in the future. I remember that I used to need safari-driver.. but with the newest version of watir-webdriver and selenium-webdriver , I don't seem to need it. Thanks for your assistance @Chuck !